# Why is variable scope dependent on the definition order?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a basic (and probably stupid) ownership question. I am trying to create a vector of `&str` from `String` values wrapped inside `Some(String)`. I am using an intermediate variable to store the extracted/unwrapped `String` and it seems I need to define this intermediary variable **before** the vector in order to satisfy the borrow checker:

Working code:

```
fn main() {
    let a = Some("a".to_string());

    let mut val = String::new();
    let mut v = Vec::<&str>::new();

    if a.is_some() {
        val = a.unwrap();
        v.push(&val[..]);
    }
    println!("{:?}", val);
}
```

Non working code:

```
fn main() {
    let a = Some("a".to_string());

    let mut v = Vec::<&str>::new();
    let mut val = String::new();

    if a.is_some() {
        val = a.unwrap();
        v.push(&val[..]);
    }
    println!("{:?}", val);
}
```

And the compiler errors:

```
<anon>:9:17: 9:20 error: `val` does not live long enough
<anon>:9         v.push(&val[..]);
                        ^~~
<anon>:4:35: 12:2 note: reference must be valid for the block suffix following statement 1 at 4:34...
<anon>:4     let mut v = Vec::<&str>::new();
<anon>:5     let mut val = String::new();
<anon>:6 
<anon>:7     if a.is_some() {
<anon>:8         val = a.unwrap();
<anon>:9         v.push(&val[..]);
        ...
<anon>:5:32: 12:2 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block suffix following statement 2 at 5:31
<anon>:5     let mut val = String::new();
<anon>:6 
<anon>:7     if a.is_some() {
<anon>:8         val = a.unwrap();
<anon>:9         v.push(&val[..]);
<anon>:10     }
        ...
error: aborting due to previous error
playpen: application terminated with error code 101
```

[The playpen code](http://is.gd/f8IM54)

The question is: why do I have to define the `val` variable before the vector `v`? As I see it, `val` scope is the same as `v` scope, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bindings are dropped in reverse order of declaration, i.e. the most recently declared thing is destroyed first. Specifically, in the code that doesn't work, the destructor of `val` runs before the destructor of `v`. Without careful consideration of what `Vec<&str>::drop()` does, this is not safe: It could for example try to look at the contents of the string slices it contains, despite the fact that the `String` from which they derive is already destroyed.

`Vec` doesn't actually do that, but other legitimate types do something along those lines. Previously it was impossible to safely implement `Drop` for types that contain lifetimes/borrowed pointers. A [relatively recent change](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/21972) makes it safe by introducing these additional restrictions.

Note that if you declare `let v, val;` or `let val, v;` and later assign, the two bindings *do* have the same lifetime, so it's not impossible to have two variables of the same lifetime.

Comment: Thanks. Defining both variables on the same line makes it work independent of the order, e.g. like this: `let (mut v, mut val) = (Vec::<&str>::new(), String::new());`

Comment: Now that brings an interesting question: in which order are `v` and `val` destroyed when they are declared at once? Because you would still need `val` to be destroyed after `v`, does the compiler infer the right order?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Good question. There are two parts to the change, one are the drop rules (that a linear type *strictly* outlives all references inside of it), and the other is that `let x; let y; ...` is parsed as `let x; { let y; { ... }}`. The latter is technically syntactic sugar, it makes it easier to meet the restriction from the first part. My best guess is that the "structly outlives" requirement doesn't apply to Vec, perhaps because it still uses `#[unsafe_destructor]` or because it has no lifetime parameter? Then both having the same lifetime would be kosher.